# How to find the top 10 pairs that appear the most in a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in python with columns 'a', 'b', 'c'. The 'a','b' pairs are unique and repeat multiple times. 'c' is changing all the time. I want to find the 10 pairs 'a','b' that appear the most and put them in a dataframe but don't know how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I follow you, but assuming you mean you have a DataFrame looking something like

```
>>> N = 1000
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (N, 3)), columns="A B C".split()) 
>>> df.head()
   A  B  C
0  7  4  5
1  5  1  3
2  8  9  8
3  2  3  0
4  2  3  0
```

and you simply want to count (A, B) pairs, that's easy enough:

```
>>> df.groupby(["A", "B"]).size().order().iloc[-10:]
A  B
6  1    13
1  0    14
4  0    14
7  2    14
1  6    15
8  2    15
1  8    16
2  6    16
6  4    16
7  4    16
dtype: int64
```

That can be broken down into four parts:

1. `groupby`, which groups the data by `(A, B)` tuples
2. `size`, which computes the size of each group
3. `order`, which returns the `Series` sorted by value
4. `iloc`, which lets us select the last 10 entries in the `Series` by position

That results in a `Series`, but you could make a `DataFrame` out of it simply by passing it to `pd.DataFrame`.